# Lose listview function using both SwipeRefreshLayout and DrawerLayout？

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, swiperefreshlayout

I am using both SwipeRefreshLayout and DrawerLayout in same xml. However Drawer works fine. But I cannot swipe the listview. Is there something wrong the xml?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.einverne.inoreader.Activity.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"></ListView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.einverne.inoreader.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my layout.xml to this to solve the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <com.einverne.inoreader.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- The navigation drawer content -->

    </com.einverne.inoreader.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

    <!-- The main content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"></ListView>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.einverne.inoreader.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```